# Azure powershell mention file path within inline script

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to use Azure PowerShell inline script to upload a file to API management. I am not able to find a way how to mention the filepath of the Artifact within the PowerShell script.

Expecting to use Azure PowerShell which uses AzureRM service connection to access the API management service and upload the swagger file as below

`Import-AzureRmApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext -SpecificationFormat "Swagger" -SpecificationPath "My_Azuredevops_repo_path_to_file" -Path "apis`

[image]

[image]

Comment: How is your problem progressing? Is KrishnaG's answer helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the path here can be mentioned by leveraging one of [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) variables. Please check the link and mention the appropriate variable.

AFAIK if it's local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded then you may need to have the variable $(Build.SourcesDirectory) / $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) / $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

Hope this helps!